# Use scraped number in function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

How can I turn a scraped data point `23FLAT`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
datapoint_one = soup.findAll(class_ = 'kinfobox').text
just_number = float(datapoint_one.strip('FLAT'))
print(just_number)
.. 23
```

and use it

```
amount = '200'
for number in numbers:
    ((just_number*int('1000'))+int(amount))
```

so that I can iterate `amount` over it multiple times

Like so

```
23200
23400
23600
...
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear the output would be `23200`, `23400`, `23600` ...

Comment: Now, i understood the second part. can you help me with inputs too. like, what is `soup_one`? what is `followers`?

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. I changed the names when uploading to stackoverflow, `soup_one` is just a standard `BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')`, and `followers` was `datapoint_one`

Comment: ok, let's make it simple. let's consider you already have some text like `23FLAT`. so, what you want is to generate number which is combination of `23` form the text and the `amount`. Am i right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question in the comment. Here is how you can do it.

let's say you want to generate n numbers.
so,

```
numbers =n
amount = '200'
your_text = "23FLAT"
just_number = your_text.strip("FLAT")
initial_number = int(just_number+amount)
amount_int = int(amount)
for i in range(numbers):
    print(initial_number + i*amount_int)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I was missing the syntax. Thank you for patient support! I am grateful for the help!!